# discord.py bot script doesn't react for list.pop() function. How to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Pretty stupid situation, I have made a discord bot that webscrapes from a specific website and should print out a joke after the command "!anekdot".

Bot itself works, it prints out the first joke. But after printing the first joke bot must pop it. However it doesn't do that (type of anekdots and its length have been used to understand if anything changes and if I can apply list's functions to anekdots list):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from script import anekdot_script


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')


anekdots = []
n_of_page = 1
@bot.command()
async def anekdot(ctx, anekdots = anekdots, n_of_page = n_of_page):
    anekdots = anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page)
    if anekdots:
        await ctx.send(type(anekdots))
        await ctx.send(anekdots[0].text)
        anekdots.pop(0)
        await ctx.send(len(anekdots))
    else:
        await ctx.send('Nothing left! Find new web-site!')


bot.run('ID')
```

I thought that making anekdots and n_of_page variables global, the problem doesn't even have to appear.
Output in discord (doesn't change at all):

```
<class 'list'>
The joke in russian...
24
```

Script just checks if the list is empty, if it's empty - the script webscrapes the page and create a list of jokes and return it:

```
def anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page): #return list of anekdots of a specific page
    url = 'https://humornet.ru/anekdot/evrei/page/{}/'


    if anekdots == []:
        response = requests.get(url.format(n_of_page)) #getting page info
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'


        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') #parses the page to html format
        anekdots = soup.select('.text') #anekdots have class 'text' on this page

        n_of_page += 1
        
    
    return list(anekdots)
```

I have tried slicing as well, didn't help at all.
I don't understand hot to make the bot update the list of jokes by removing the printed out joke.

Comment: you run `anekdot_script()` inside commnad `!anekdot` so it always get again all jokes and using `pop(0)` makes no sends because next command `!anekdot` will get again all jokes. You have to get all jokes only once - at start of bot. Or you would have to use some variable to control if you have to read new jokes or not. AND using `anekdots = ...`inside function creates local variable `anekdots` and it doesn't replace exteran list `anekdots = []`. You would have to use `global anekdots` inside function to replace external `anekdots = []`.

Comment: Global assigmnet inside of function is impossible because I have assigned variables outside of the function. Also anekdot_script() firstly checks if anekdots is empty and create a new list only in this case. So it shouldn't create a new list all the time. Btw, I have typed len(anekdots) inside of func in order to check if list changes and then recreates. But it doesn't change at all after anekdots.pop(0)

Comment: def anekdot by default takes global n_of_page and anekdots list. I run the command only like "!anekdot", so inside of function I already have global variables, which must be modified

Comment: but you create new local variable `anekdots` using `anekdots = anekdot_script()` - even if there is global `anekdots = []` - you have to use `global anekdots` to assign back to global variable. Besides I don't know what you are doing in `anekdot_script()` - if it get the same jokes then it assing again the same jokes to `anekdots` with jokes which you tried to remove using `pop()`

Comment: in other words: first `!anekdot` runs `anekdot_script()` which gives `["A", "B", "C"]`, and you display `"A"` and you use `pop()` to remove `"A". But next `!anekdot` runs again `anekdot_script()` and it gives again `["A", "B", "C"]` so your `pop` was useless. You would have to run `anekdot_script()` only once - before start bot - or you should check if list `anekdots` is empty and then use `anekdot_script()` to get new jokes.

Comment: I run code and I found few problem - first global `anekdots` and local `anekdots`, next there is not local `anekdots` but rather argument `def anekdot(..., anekdots=... )` which is treaded as even different variable. third using `def anekdot(..., anekdots=anekdots )` you assign reference to global list `[]` but later `anekdots = anekdot_script()` will replace this reference in `global variable but it will not replace in def anekdot(..., anekdots=anekdots )` so it will still use empty list `[]`.

Comment: I will try it again. I got your idea. Will try to make a global variable. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with two (or maybe even three) different variables with the same name `anekdots`

There is global variable

```
anekdots = []
```

local variable

```
anekdots = anekdot_script(...)
```

which not really is local variable but rather `parameter variable` created in

```
async def anekdot(..., anekdots = ...)
```

and all this makes mess because you think that you assign to global variable but code assign it to local variable and next time it uses again `anekdots = []` when it runs `anekdot_script()` and it reads again all jokes.

This works for me

```
anekdots = []
n_of_page = 1

@bot.command()
async def anekdot(ctx):
    global anekdots   # inform function that `anekdots = ...` has to assign to global variable instead of creating local one
    global n_of_page  # inform function that `n_of_page = ...` has to assign to global variable instead of creating local one

    anekdots, n_of_page = anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page)
```

with

```
def anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page):
    # ... code ...
    return anekdots, n_of_page # need to return also `n_of_page`
```

---

Full working code but it doesn't get extra arguments in command `!anekdot`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
def anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page): #return list of anekdots of a specific page
    url = 'https://humornet.ru/anekdot/evrei/page/{}/'

    if not anekdots:
        response = requests.get(url.format(n_of_page)) #getting page info
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'


        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') #parses the page to html format
        anekdots = soup.select('.text') #anekdots have class 'text' on this page

        n_of_page += 1
    
    return anekdots, n_of_page # need to return also `n_of_page`


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!')

anekdots = []
n_of_page = 1

@bot.command()
async def anekdot(ctx):
    global anekdots   # inform function that `anekdots = ...` has to assign to global variable instead of creating local one
    global n_of_page  # inform function that `n_of_page = ...` has to assign to global variable instead of creating local one

    anekdots, n_of_page = anekdot_script(anekdots, n_of_page)

    if anekdots:
        await ctx.send(type(anekdots))
        await ctx.send(anekdots[0].text)
        anekdots.pop(0)
        await ctx.send(len(anekdots))
    else:
        await ctx.send('Nothing left! Find new web-site!')

import os
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I have realised that I've made too much confusion with the scope of variables. I got your explanation! Thank you very much for yout help! Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I am not familiar with Discord Bots. This is just a common way to solve the problem**

You can try storing all the printed jokes in a list and check everytime if it was printed earlier.

```py
jokes = []    #Create a empty list
    
def get_and_print():    #Get your jokes
    while True:
        #get joke as myJoke
        if myJoke in jokes:
            #get new joke
        else:
            break
    print(myJoke)
    jokes.append(myJoke)    #Insert it in jokes list
```

You can also delete any joke if the list size exceeds, say 100

```py
if len(jokes) > 100:
    jokes.pop(-1)
```